# How to access my web application with and without / at the end of the URL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In my opinion I have a very simple problem, but I am not able to figure out a working solution.

I have been following web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/article/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If I access my web application from following url `http://localhost/article` everthing works fine. If I add a slash at the end, the application run into an ifinitie loop.

I knew this is produced by the `getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(req, resp)` call and the web.xml configuration entry `/article/*`.

If I change `index.jsp` to `/index.jsp`, I get forwarded correctly, but all resources are sill mapped to the wrong path. For example, the css files are mapped to *article/css* instead of *css*. I think this happens because the getRequestDispatcher, keeps the contextPath.

The index.jsp is placed in the root directory.

How could I access `http://localhost/article` and `http://localhost/article/`?

Comment: i think when you add `/` after `article` it process by your servlet but `article` without `/` not process by your servlet

Comment: Both cases are processed by the servlet. I verified it, with the debugger, also the attributes for the jsp get insert with `article`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that:

- the static resources are relative to the JSP on your file system
- the URLs are relative

The browser is going to resolve relative URLs relative to the current URL. You can use the application's context path to provide the correct path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/css/foo.css">
```

Now it doesn't matter what the request URL is or what the application context path is; the links will be resolved correctly.

*The expression is a bit verbose but you could always shorten it with an application-scoped copy of the string.*

Comment: WOW - I was stuck into the servlet solution that I forgot about this possibility. Thanks alot!